# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{\log n}}n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^{\log n}}n$$

The exercise requires to study the series for $a\in \mathbb{R} > 0$. The case $a\geq 1$ is very simple. I can't wrap my head around the remaining cases though. Anyone?

Comment: **Hint:** $a^{\ln n}=n^{\ln a}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$a^{\log n}=\mathrm e^{\log a\cdot\log n}=n^{\log a}.$$